# Is there a way to edit the IK Goals in a Unity Humanoid Animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am currently trying to transfer one animation from a character to another. I have configured both characters as humanoids, and they share the same Animator, however on the second character the animation has some unexpected movement.

[Wrong (new character)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oeI7.png) 
[Correct (original)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFnrk.png)

The IK Goals generated by Unity seem to try to force the position of the animation from the other model, instead of scaling it to fit the new size. This makes it so that instead of having the hands still on the "floor", the new character's hands keep moving up and down.
Also, the skeleton and rig is the same on both characters.

I can't seem to find any fix to this, any help would be much appreciated :)